# OpenLayers 6: Exemplo Box Selection Erro

Tags: openlayers

Seguindo exatamente o exemplo do site openlayers em:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html?q=feature

Localmente, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getObject (JSONFeature.js: 197)
    at GeoJSON.JSONFeature.readFeatures (JSONFeature.js: 53)
    at VectorSource. <anonymous> (featureloader.js: 94)
```

Acredito que o erro ocorre ao tentar carregar um arquivo geojson localmente.

```
var vectorSource = new VectorSource ({
  url: 'data / geojson / countries.geojson',
  format: new GeoJSON ()
});
```

**O countries.geojson como é bastante extenso, deixo o link de onde baixei o arquivo**:
https://r68tk.csb.app/data/geojson/countries.geojson

Como resolver?

Comment: Tem como postar o código do seu arquivo `countries.geojson`?

Comment: leofalmeida , como arquivo é muito grande, deixo o link dele:  https://r68tk.csb.app/data/geojson/countries.geojson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu encontrei a solução.

No processo de desenvolvimento de um aplicativo no OpenLayers, infelizmente, há problemas ao carregar arquivos localmente (geojson, png etc.) devido a política de mesa origem, ou seja, o **CORS**.

**O problema:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um excelente texto sobre o assunto [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server).

Para solucionar o problema, usei a extensão do Chrome chamada "[moesif CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US)".

Com ela ativada, consegui carregar facilmente o arquivo .geojson.

**Tudo certo! Dados do Mapa carregado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há ainda mais maneiras de parar o CORS no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento neste endereço: [https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control- permitir -origin-works-d97d55946d9](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-%20permitir%20-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

Espero ajudar alguém com esta informação!